# Rcpp subsetting NumericVector with Datetime variable

Tags: r, rcpp

I would like to subset a xts object in a specific interval of dates and then perform some computations. R is not able to handle my problem, so I decided to try Rcpp.

I am new to C++ and I am learning as I go along. But what I want to do is something that is equivalent to

```
     Y <- X['2017-01-01::2019-01-01']

     computations on Y

     proceed to next range of dates
```

At this point I can only extract dates from the xts object in Rcpp following the Rcpp examples page:

```
DatetimeVector I = NumericVector(X.attr("index"));
```

But none of my attempts to subset seems work:

```
Y[wrap(as<Datetime>(I[0]))];
```

or

```
Y[wrap(as<int>)(I[0]))];
```

Do you guys have any place where I can learn to properly do this, or know what is the correct
way to perform this subsetting?

**EDIT**

As it was mentioned in the comments, I could use the data.table package.
But even so, computations still run slowly. I am doing the following

```
# Vector of beginning dates: in1;
# Vector of ending dates: in2;

Answer <- list()
for(i in 1:length(in1)){
  Answer[[i]] <- Rt[I>=in1[i] & I<=in2[i], lapply(.SD, rcpp_Functions), .SDcols = 2:ncol(Rt)]
}
```

So the questions are then: Is this the most efficient way when using data.table? Is there a way to put this computation in Rcpp?

Comment: "R is not able to handle my problem."  Maybe we can help you with that.  What you describe I tend to now with `data.table` as it is _by far_ the fastest way to results.  I use Rcpp as well, of course, for more for dedicated tasks.

Comment: I have 2701 series and 3440 different date ranges. For each range, I want to perform 5 different computations on each of the 2701 series. I translated the computations to Rcpp and helped A LOT, but still I cannot loop through the whole range of dates in an acceptable time.

Comment: That is exactly what on of the things that `data.table` is excellent at.  I found this video quite helpful, maybe you like it too:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztTDLefpPVY&feature=youtu.be&t=1m54s Corresponding slides are at https://github.com/billcgold/presentations/tree/master/data.table-nyhackr_2018-09-17 -- and you can still call your Rcpp-based function for the inner computation.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this package. It is very powerful indeed, but I am still unsure how to solve my problem. Maybe I am using it wrong.